# how to create a bokeh colormapper in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I would like to do the equivalent of the following Python in stand-alone BokehJS

```
color_mapper = bokeh.models.mappers.LogColorMapper('Viridis256',low=vmin,high=vmax)
```

How do I do it?  Where are the color mappers located in the javascript CDN files?
They don't seem to be here, for example:

```
https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.7.js
```

and not here either:

```
https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.7.js
```

I am trying to follow examples like these:

```
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html#minimal-complete-example
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading Bokeh docs and js source this seems to work with version 0.12.5

```
var color_mapper = new Bokeh.LogColorMapper({palette:'Viridis256', low:0, high:16});
```

I did try to get some sane result in example below but without much success. Maybe you can improve this code further. This is based on python source from [Updating color mapper in a bokeh plot with taptool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212721/updating-color-mapper-in-a-bokeh-plot-with-taptool#43214378)
Try to click on button "Add some data!" many times, more then 10.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.5.min.css" type="text/css"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.5.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.5.min.js"></script>
  <title> by bokeh</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="myplot" />
</div>
<button onclick="addPoint()">Add some data!</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
// arrays to hold data
var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
  data: { x: [Math.random() * 10.0], y: [Math.random() * 10.0], humidity: [0, 10.0] }
});
var color_mapper = new Bokeh.LogColorMapper({palette:'Viridis256', low:0, high:16});

// make the plot and add some tools
var tools = "pan,crosshair,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save";

var plot = Bokeh.Plotting.figure({title:'Example of Random data', tools: tools, height: 300, width: 300});

var pglyph = plot.patches({ field: "x" }, { field: "y" },
    { fill_color: { field: "humidity", transform: color_mapper}},
                   { source: source, alpha: 1, line_width: 4})

var scatterData = plot.line({ field: "x" }, { field: "y" },
    { source: source, line_width: 10 });

// Show the plot, appending it to the end of the current
// section of the document we are in.
Bokeh.Plotting.show(plot, document.getElementById('myplot'));

function addPoint() {
  // The data can be added, but generally all fields must be the
  // same length.
  source.data.x.push(Math.random() * 10.0);
  source.data.y.push(Math.random() * 10.0);
  // Also, the DataSource object must be notified when it has changed.
  source.trigger('change');
}
//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Models are located inside the main JS file (at least, for Bokeh 0.12.9): https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.9.js

You can get `LogColorMapper` in your code by using:

```
Bokeh.require('models/mappers/log_color_mapper').LogColorMapper
```